# How can I rewrite option of select2

Tags: jquery-select2

[image: p1]
[image: p2]
    This is my js code:

```js
function getCompany(){
         var url = _reqCtx + "/extReport/getCompany.action";
         function callback(response){
          $("#searchForm").find("#companyId").select2({
           data : response
          });
         };
         $.post(url,{},callback);
        }
```

I want the "& nbsp;" in p1 can be parsed space like p2 use select2. The
 data was given by the others,so I can't change it . So , how can I
 rewrite the option of select2 .Any tips will be helpful . Thx very
 much !

Comment: You will have to "clean" the data before applying to select2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

You should move the &nbsp options as "children", see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odbe1ewt/)

```
function getCompany(){
        var url = _reqCtx + "/extReport/getCompany.action";
        function callback(response){
            nested_data = [];
            // PSEUDO CODE
            for (line in data){
               if line has &nbsp then
               Replace &nbsp and move them into children property
            }
            // END OF PSEUDO CODE

            $("#searchForm").find("#companyId").select2({
                data : nested_data
            });
        };
        $.post(url,{},callback);
    }
```

Comment: It's useful ,but the result has no level ...Space is missing

Comment: Actually , I  wanna select2 to parse the  '&nbsp;' as a html placeholder

Comment: Thank you very much ~ Chinese?